Arduino can not drive a BJT connected to a relay
I'm trying to make a simple 24V relay driven by an Arduino Leonardo as per the following picture:

The Arduino code simply toggles the output every 2 seconds. When I measured the pin voltage alone,  it varied from 5.24 to 1.34 volts but when I connected it to the relay, it started ON continuously.
I checked the voltage again and it showed very little variation on the transistor base, even without a resistor. (shown in the picture)
I use the 24V adapter to drive both the relay and buzzer connected to the relay.
Why can't the Arduino drive the BJT?
I tried other BJTs like 2N3904 and 2N3906 with the same result.

Is this a simulation problem or did you actually build this circuit?

The pin voltage isn’t going low enough to switch off the BJT.  It needs to be <0.5V and certainly should be capable of that.  Perhaps try a different pin?

If you attempted to drive the transistor without the base resistor, you may have damaged the Arduino output pin. I would suggest using a base resistor, such as 220 ohm or even a 470 ohm resistor to drive the 2N2222A.

hrsk, Please provide a datasheet for the relay. Here's a table found in one such datasheet. Your relay may require more current. But this one doesn't seem like much current. So you don't need to drive the transistor's base too hard. Also, note that in this case it's only guaranteed to operate the relay if the voltage across the relay is 19.2 V. And that it is only guaranteed to release the relay if the voltage across it is less than 2.4 V. I'd be thinking about a zener with your diode.

I built the circuit and also tried to use different resistors from 100 to 1k , and the relay I used jzc-32faz10dc24v

With about 1kΩ in series with the base, disconnect the Arduino pin and connect it instead to 0V/5V if the relay clicks, the problem is with the Arduino. If the relay does not click, the problem is on the other side.

What is going on between Pin 1 and Pin 4 of the relay?

@SpehroPefhany you were right, the Arduino pin was damaged

The pin does not go to zero which seems not right but it is the case. In fact logic zero is way above Vbe. It is about 2 VBe. Try R1 330 Ω and place a 150 Ω resistor between the base and emitter.
